# Trouble installing Magento - "continue" doesn't work

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, install, nginx, mysql-config

I am installing magento for the first time on my localhost, and I'm having trouble at database configuration step. I am installing the CE 1.7 version.

These are my settings:

[image]
[image]

When I click on continue, it reloads the same page instead of going to the admin page. I took the sample data for this magento version and created mysql database with above mentioned name, and created a new user, gave the user permissions for that db, before this step. Also, I set permissions 777 to the magento directory, but still no use. Tried all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927197/magento-installation-stuck-at-configuration), but still getting the same error. I have restarted mysql, php-fpm, but still getting the same error.

I'm running on bitnami nginx stack. I will provide the conf files if you want. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this up and running after making some weird changes. I don't understand why it worked though.

I have changed the app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910156/1076075) from

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql/>
</extensions>
```

to

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql>1</pdo_mysql>
</extensions>
```

But doing this DIDN'T solve the problem! In fact, the installer page now went into a redirect loop. I have reverted this change, and restarted the stack again.

This time, it was showing error messages when I was clicking on continue (strange). I have changed the connection host to `127.0.0.1` in app/etc/config.xml and this time it gave an error message like this: `Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message`.

Checking the `Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step` box as mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6808/17030) fixed the problem. Now the site is up and running... thanks to everyone! :)

Comment: Yes, the solution is to check the "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step" box if you or anybody see similar behaviors. Glad to know that your issue has been resolved. :)